# Rails 4: I18n::InvalidLocaleData

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, locale, kaminari

I installed the `Kaminari` gem and followed the instructions. I customized my theme to the `foundations` but when trying to further customize the pagination style using the `en.yml` file, I run into this error:

```
I18n::InvalidLocaleData in Campaigns#index

can not load translations from /myapp/config/locales/en.yml: #<Psych::SyntaxError: (/myapp/config/locales/en.yml): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 23 column 3>

Extracted source (around line #2):

1  <li>
2    <%= link_to_unless current_page.first?, raw(t 'views.pagination.first'), url, :remote => remote %>
3  </li>
```

I simply copied and pasted what was in the docs..

```
en:
  hello: "Hello world"
    pagination:
      first: "&laquo; First"
      last: "Last &raquo;"
      previous: "&lsaquo; Prev"
      next: "Next &rsaquo;"
      truncate: "&hellip;"
```

If I delete everything other than `pagination:` line, the error still remains. I'm not super familiar with the locale file in Rails as well as YAML files so any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the results from [YAML Lint](http://www.yamllint.com/), it appears that the `hello: "Hello world"` line is invalid.

Also, it looks like the `views.pagination.first` line in your code is looking for a path like: `views -> pagination -> first` in your YAML file *(and because this pattern can't be found, there's another error)*.

Therefore, it might be better to use [this kind of YAML example](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/blob/master/README.rdoc#i18n-and-labels):

```
en:
  views:
    pagination:
      first: "&laquo; First"
      last: "Last &raquo;"
      previous: "&lsaquo; Prev"
      next: "Next &rsaquo;"
      truncate: "&hellip;"
```